# Regular expression with comments does not work

Tags: php, regex

The following code does not produce the expected results, even though it should. But if you comment out the pattern that uses comments and use the single-line version, it does work. Can you think of what might be the problem?

```
define('USER_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH', 8);
define('USER_PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH', 15);

$password = 'mlk45jl64pfw';

//$pattern = '/^(?=[a-zA-Z]*?\d)(?=\d*?[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{8,15}$/x';
///*
$pattern = '/^
             (?=[a-zA-Z]*?\d)                # Checks if the string contains at least one digit
             (?=\d*?[a-zA-Z])                # Checks if the string contains at least one letter either in lower- or upper-case
             [a-zA-Z\d]{                     # Overall the string must consist of only digits and letters, regardless of capitalization for the latter'
             . USER_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH . ', # Password minimum length'
             . USER_PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH . '} # Password maximum length
             $/x';
//*/


if (preg_match($pattern, $password)) {
    echo "<p>Password is valid.</p>\n";
} else {
    echo "<p>Password is not valid.</p>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echo'ing the pattern in a pre tag results in this:

```
/^
             (?=[a-zA-Z]*?\d)                # Checks if the string contains at least one digit
             (?=\d*?[a-zA-Z])                # Checks if the string contains at least one letter either in lower- or upper-case
             [a-zA-Z\d]{                     # Overall the string must consist of only digits and letters, regardless of capitalization for the latter8, # Password minimum length15} # Password maximum length
             $/x
```

You don't have a newline after the comments that you end with the single quote to concatenate inside of the quotes so the next line appears as part of the comment. Then you end up with the opening curly brace that would result in a bad pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
 '/^
  (?=[a-zA-Z]*?\d)                  # Checks if the string contains at least one digit
  (?=\d*?[a-zA-Z])                  # Checks if the string contains at least one letter either in lower- or upper-case
  [a-zA-Z\d]{                       # Overall the string must consist of only digits and letters, regardless of capitalization for the latter
  ' . USER_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH . ', # Password minimum length
  ' . USER_PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH . '} # Password maximum length
  $/x';
```